# Problems installing Kivy on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, windows-10, kivy

I'm following the instructions on the docs https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html

And have got to the stage

```
Install kivy:

python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1
```

Everything before this has worked fine. I have checked my python version and pip version using --verison. I have Python 3.8.1 and pip 20.0.2 (python 3.8).

First of all that step didn't work and I got `ERROR: Failed building wheel for kivy`

So I looked around and saw that I can download a wheel directly. So I downloaded `https://kivy.org/downloads/appveyor/kivy/Kivy-2.0.0rc1.20200130.318720360-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`
I figured this would be the correct version as I have python 3.8 and 64 bit processor.

However when I try `python -m pip install Kivy-2.0.0rc1.20200130.318720360-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Kivy-2.0.0rc1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Kivy-2.0.0rc1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64
```

**EDIT** Full error behind `ERROR: Failed building wheel for kivy`:

```
    C:\Users\User>python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1
Collecting kivy==1.11.1
  Using cached Kivy-1.11.1.tar.gz (23.6 MB)
Processing c:\users\user\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\d2\72\1a\9ddd17f00755707937caa350616965fb3330a6270425f397e6\kivy_garden-0.1.4-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting docutils
  Using cached docutils-0.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl (548 kB)
Collecting pygments
  Using cached Pygments-2.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (896 kB)
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2019.11.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: kivy
  Building wheel for kivy (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477:
   command: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i_dh93mc\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i_dh93mc\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-q23wvn82'
       cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i_dh93mc\kivy\
  Complete output (531 lines):
  Using setuptools
  User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
  Using this graphics system: OpenGL
  WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

  b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

  WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

  b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

  WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

  b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

  ERROR: Dependency for context.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for texture.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for vbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for vertex.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
  fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\animation.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\app.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\atlas.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  copying kivy\base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
  **lots more of this, cut for char limit**

  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for kivy
  Running setup.py clean for kivy
Failed to build kivy
Installing collected packages: urllib3, idna, chardet, certifi, requests, Kivy-Garden, docutils, pygments, kivy
    Running setup.py install for kivy ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477:
     command: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i_dh93mc\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i_dh93mc\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-817ny_l6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Include\kivy'
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i_dh93mc\kivy\
    Complete output (513 lines):
    Using setuptools
    User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
    Using this graphics system: OpenGL
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

    fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
    copying kivy\animation.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
    copying kivy\app.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
    copying kivy\atlas.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy
    ** again cut due to char limit **

    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\tab_btn_pressed.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\tab_disabled.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\textinput.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\textinput_active.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\textinput_disabled.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\textinput_disabled_active.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\tree_closed.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\tree_opened.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\vkeyboard_background.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\vkeyboard_disabled_background.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\vkeyboard_disabled_key_down.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\vkeyboard_disabled_key_normal.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\vkeyboard_key_down.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    copying kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme\vkeyboard_key_normal.png -> build\lib.win32-3.8\kivy\tools\theming\defaulttheme
    running build_ext
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i_dh93mc\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i_dh93mc\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-817ny_l6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Include\kivy' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Can you edit to include the full error behind `ERROR: Failed building wheel for kivy`

Comment: Sure I'll edit in a sec... It's a big one

Comment: Thank you, this will help to figure out why the source built fails. As to why installing the `whl` file fails, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1` can only download the source distribution from pypi, as there is no whl file available for python 3.8 on pypi. Building the source package seems to fail, which can have a couple of reasons

Additionally, you have installed 32 bit python (probably unintentionally), as you can see by the installation location `Python38-32`. That is why your `whl` file cannot be installed, as it is for win**64**. I would suggest to uninstall your python and reinstall a 64 bit version

Comment: Update... tried it with .whl and got this `ERROR: Kivy-2.0.0rc1.20200130.318720360-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: Can you execute in the terminal `python -c "import wheel.pep425tags as w; print(w.get_supported())"`?

Comment: `C:\Users\User>python -c "import wheel.pep425tags as w; print(w.get_supported())"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: get_supported() missing 1 required positional argument: 'archive_root'`

Answer (score 15):

Try using this. Worked for me in the same case.

```
pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
```

worked on python 3.8.2 both 32 and 64 bit, os: win10

Comment: Thank you! This worked great but could you explain why it worked?

Comment: @simon the normal releases of kivy (downloadable through pip) ar made for python 3.7 or previous versions. So they don't run on 3.8 . However they made one for 3.8 and kept it in thier git repo (may be under development or something) so we (the python 3.8 users) need to install it from there.

Comment: working on latest 3.8.6 as well
but not working on py 3.9.0rc2 yet (tested)

Comment: this solution works on almost every latest stable python version that got released (kinda like the beta support version of kivy)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the lower link to install kivy in my windows 10.
I am using python 3.9.
Hope it will also work for you.

https://kivy.org/doc/stable-1.10.1/installation/installation-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

I used the command refered in <12> and worked for me I am using python 3.10.2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).